# Python Determine week of Year (non-ISO way)

Tags: .net, python

Is there a pythonic way of getting the equivalent of the following in .NET?

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(dt.Date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday)
```

`dt.isocalendar()[1]` does not seem to work for me as it returns 53 (expecting 52) for `datetime.date(2010, 1, 1)`

Thanks.

Comment: Decided to take Zooba's advice and wrote a function to mimic the implementation of date.getisocalendar()[1] but for the month, so the first week will be the week with the 4'th or the first week with a Thursday. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ISO calendar has a range of confusing rules that are likely the source of the issues you face here. In particular, the .NET implementation of `GetWeekOfYear` (with the parameters you have used) is so similar to ISO that [explicit clarifications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnste/archive/2006/01/24/iso-8601-week-of-year-format-in-microsoft-net.aspx) are required and linked from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendarweekrule.aspx). The result is that `isocalendar` and `GetWeekOfYear` will produce results that differ [my emphasis]:

> Specifically ISO 8601 always has 7 day weeks.  If the first partial week of a year doesn't contain Thursday, then it is counted as the last week of the previous year.  Likewise, **if the last week of the previous year doesn't contain Thursday then its treated like the first week of the next year**.  GetWeekOfYear() has the first behavior, but not the second.

Some suggestions for correcting `GetWeekOfYear` are discussed at the link above and also at [Is .NET giving me the wrong week number for Dec. 29th 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428957/is-net-giving-me-the-wrong-week-number-for-dec-29th-2008) If you actually want to match the `GetWeekOfYear` behaviour these two links will assist, although you will be applying the reverse transformation to their examples.

The most 'Pythonic' way of doing it is to create a function. Nothing particularly special here, except the usual attempt to minimise code by doing things like `day < 4` rather than `day == 1 or day == 2 ...` etc.

(Of course, all of this is assuming that Python's `isocalendar` correctly matches the ISO calendar. The documentation seems to suggest that it does, where the `GetWeekOfYear` explicitly states that it doesn't, so it would seem a reasonable assumption. However, if this is a critical calculation, you will be testing it thoroughly yourself anyway.)

Comment: That's what I thought. I thought I may have missed something in the calendar documentation. I'll write a function to implement this.