# .NET Calendar.GetWeekOfYear returning incorrect result for en-US

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, calendar, cultureinfo

I searched for a similar post, but none seemed to answer this question.

For dates *01/01/2005* and *12/28/2008*, the week number should be 1, according to the the *timeanddate.com* web-site, assuming it's correct:

[01/01/2005](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/custom.html?year=2005&country=1&cols=0&lang=en&wno=1&cdt=31&typ=0&display=3&df=1) and [12/28/2008](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=2008&country=1)

Problem is, the C# code I have produces the correct week number result for *01/01/2005*, but an incorrect result for *12/28/2008*, returning 53, instead of 1:

```
CultureInfo clUS = new CultureInfo( "en-US", false );

int wkNm = clUS.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
  new DateTime( 2005, 1, 1, clUS.Calendar ),
  clUS.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule,
  clUS.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek
);  // returns 1

wkNm = clUS.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
  new DateTime( 2008, 12, 28, clUS.Calendar ),
  clUS.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule,
  clUS.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek
);  // returns 53
```

For `CalendarWeekRule` and `FirstDayOfWeek`, I'm using the default options for the en-US culture.

Comment: Isn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428957/is-net-giving-me-the-wrong-week-number-for-dec-29th-2008?rq=1) the same thing?

Comment: It's close, that post relating to ISO 8601, I'm looking at en-US. I *think* the timeanddate.com calendar is wrong. According to Wikipedia (http://bit.ly/11gklmV), Canada, US & Mexico, first week of the year has 1st of January and the 1st Saturday. The timeanddate.com web-site for 2008 (US), shows the last week in December as week 1, but has no 1st of January nor 1st Saturday. If I look at the CalendarLabs web-site (http://bit.ly/zcHkD), it shows the final week of December as week 53, which would seem correct.

Answer (score 0):

A description of the issue is available from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnste/archive/2006/01/24/iso-8601-week-of-year-format-in-microsoft-net.aspx)

I use the method below for the `CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek` rule - it checks what **Thursday's** week number is (using the same .NET method) because Thursday is the day that actually matters when using that rule and Microsoft's code gets that right all the time :)

```
    private static int WeekNumber(DateTime date)
    {
        var dayOffset = DayOfWeek.Thursday - date.DayOfWeek;
        if (dayOffset > 0)
            date = date.AddDays(dayOffset);

        return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
    }
```

Comment: Thursday isn't the day that actually matters for the options in the question, so this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you for sharing that article.